# Trouble setup PHPUnit and Selenium testing environment on Windows

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I have trouble setting up PHPUnit and Selenium testing environment on Windows 7 x64 machine. Apache/2.4.20 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.11.

My composer.json files looks like this (snipet):

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.0",
    "psr/http-message": "^1.0",
    "psr/cache": "^1.0",
    "zendframework/zend-diactoros": "^1.3",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.6",
    "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": "^3.0"
},
```

I have the following components downloaded already:

- selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1 from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
- chromedriver_win32.zip (ofc extracted) from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.27/

all the files are stored in the folder `D:\dev\selenium\`.

Selenium server is started by issuin the following command `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:\dev\selenium\chromedriver.exe" -jar "D:\dev\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar"`
in command prompt.

I was searchring all day long on Google but found nothing; this is why I am asking you guys. When I'am trying to run tests by executing the command `phpunit` in project folder I get no result. Chrome opens up with the URL `data:;` and closes immadiately. Firefox is worst, it doesn't even opens. Standard PHPUnit tests are executin properly and I can see the results of those.

-- Edit --

Forgot to mention I am using Chrome version 55.0.2883.87 m x64.
If somebody could suggest version combination all of these which actually works I would be really happy.

-- Edit 2 --

Java version: 8 update 111

Console output of Selenium server:

```
09:50:06.651 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75'
09:50:06.651 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
2017-01-09 09:50:06.682:INFO::main: Logging initialized @414ms
09:50:06.745 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
09:50:06.745 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver registration is skipped:
Unable to create new instances on this machine.
09:50:06.745 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
09:50:06.745 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
09:50:06.760 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver regi
stration is skipped: registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, platform
=MAC}] does not match the current platform VISTA
2017-01-09 09:50:06.807:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.15.v20160210
2017-01-09 09:50:06.823:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@f5e5e3{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-01-09 09:50:06.994:INFO:osjs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@c4039c{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:4444}
2017-01-09 09:50:06.994:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @739ms
09:50:06.994 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
```

-- Edit 3 --

```
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: The best matching driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver can't create a new driver instance for Capabilities [{browserName=*firefox}]
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: '****', ip: '10.10.146.251', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86 (????)', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Can not believe that nobody responded yet. Almost two days and I could not get closer to the solution. Anyhow I am currently considering Codeception as an alternative, it is a shame the Selenium does not have better support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/issues/295#issuecomment-259398666

Based on your current code, this is how your web test file should look.
This works for Chromedriver 2.25,  phpunit 5.6.3, phpunit-selenium 3.0.2 and the standalone selenium server 3.0.1 and assumes you are running tests locally (E.g *NOT* across selenium hubs on remote machines through jenkins etc)

I have added a couple of method overrides from `Selenium2TestCase`, one of which will fix the `data://` error you get in your original question when running code coverage (`prepareSession`) and a useful helper function which captures screenshots on test failures (`onNotSuccessfulTest`)

Try using the following as your test class:

```
namespace Acceptance\Tests;

use PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase;

class BaseWebTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    // Remove: not needed
    /*public static $browsers = [
        [
            'browserName' => 'chrome',
            'host'        => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'        => 4444,
            'sessionStrategy' => 'shared'
        ]
    ];*/

    /**
     * Make sure parent setUp is called
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp(); 

        $this->setHost($host); // localhost
        $this->setPort((int)$port); // 4444
        $this->setBrowser($browser); // chrome
        $this->setBrowserUrl($application); // localhost/your_app (NOT just localhost)
        $this->prepareSession()->currentWindow()->size(array('width' => 1920, 'height' => 1080)); // maximise window area
    }

    /**
     * Ensure the session begins with a url that cookies can be set against.
     * Without this calling the tester with code coverage breaks.
     *
     * @see https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/issues/295#issuecomment-259398666
     *
     * @return object
     */
    public function prepareSession()
    {
        $session = parent::prepareSession();
        $this->url('/');

        return $session;
    }

    /**
     * Override this method from \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase so we can capture a screenshot.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function onNotSuccessfulTest($exception)
    {
        $filedata   = $this->currentScreenshot();
        $file       = 'YOUR\SCREENSHOT\DIR\HERE\\' . basename(get_class($this)) . '.png';
        file_put_contents($file, $filedata);

        parent::onNotSuccessfulTest($exception);
    }

    public function testTitle()
    {
        $this->url('http://localhost/');
        $this->assertEquals('Virtual host localhost configured', $this->title());
    }
}
```

Make sure selenium is actually running by calling this in a separate window:

```
START java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=E:\path\to\chromedriver.exe -jar E:\path\to\selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar
```

Comment: I have something strange going on. Today I tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriver-manager together with http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver and tried the PHP code you wrote, but still doesn't work. Anyhow I appreciate your effort, thank you @john-joseph

Comment: The code above is for phpunit-selenium, so it would only work when using that library.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but as of today neither seems to work. I am thinking setting up a virtual machine installing fresh Windows 7, Selenium, Composer and see if it works. I am not mixing the Codeception test files with the previous setup just to mention. /smile

Comment: Could you add some code to your question? particularly the web test case you are trying to run (for phpunit-selenium). I may be able to resolve it if I can see your test code.

Comment: I've prepared information here: http://pastebin.com/ksnRY0Cs - Selenium server log: http://pastebin.com/TB8S1E9A

Comment: OK, so now you have a different selenium error to the one specified in the question in that pastebin ... I am using Chromedriver 2.25 with selenium 3.0.1, and the latest phpunit-selenium. The code applied in my answer above works for those combinations, so try those (downgrade to chromedriver 2.25)

Comment: With Chromedriver 2.25 I get `Starting ChromeDriver 2.25.426923 (xxxxx) on port 13500 Only local connections are allowed.` response.

Comment: Sorry a little bit late according stackowerflow, but there is the full Selenium log: http://pastebin.com/aas6rHsM

Comment: Chromedriver v2.8 seems to work on http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html I was abble to create session; and tried to run tests too, but recived error message: Google chrome started and exited: `unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"3416.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}   (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)`

Comment: I will update my answer with additional code and info.

Comment: All together I get the following error: `PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Exception: There is currently no active ses
sion to execute the 'currentScreenshot' command. You're probably trying to set s
ome option in setUp() with an incorrect setter name. You may consider using setU
pPage() instead.`

Comment: Answer updated again - I'd missed out some settings. Use that full test case in my answer, it should work now.

Comment: With a slightly modification it work on a Virtual Machine! That is a huge step, this means there is something wrong on my dev machine.  On vm I was able to run the test it took the screenshot, no error or what so ever. But on my dev machine I still get "Only local connections are allowed." - the rest of the error message is the same as previously. Sorry for the long delay, setting up everything on vm took awhile.

Comment: On a  side note, Google Chrome had no addons installed nor I was logged i.; I havn't seen that pesky ssl warning bar. I'll try to uninstall and remove directories registry entries and reinstall Chrome just to see what happens.

Comment: I would suggest we abandon this, it is not worth puting more work and research time into this for our own sanity. I won't forget your help and kindnes to help me in this; really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: No problem :) ask another question if you need to do with updated data, as this one has become a bit clogged up now!